# My question is about loading "html code" the right way into iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have some code which creates an `Iframe` and links its `src` to an empty HTML file *info.html*. Then, it loads a block of HTML code to the *info.html* page.

The code works well but Chrome browser complains and produces the following error to the console:

```
[Violation] Avoid using document.write()
```

**My code**

```js
let a = document.getElementById("box-content");
let c = document.createElement("iframe");
c.src = "info.html";
c.id  = "cnd_iframe";
a.appendChild(c);

let iframe = document.getElementById(c.id);
let iDoc   = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

let i_content = `<!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html lang="en">
                        <head>
                            <title>Title</title>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                          <p>Demo Setup</p>
                        </body>
                        </html>`;
iDoc.open();
iDoc.write(i_content);
iDoc.close();
```

**My Attempts**

I planned on using `appendChild` but it won't work because `i_content` is a string.
I also tried using Blob as shown below but it won't work because it would override the iframe src

```js
var i_blob     = new Blob([i_content], {type: 'text/html'});
var new_iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");

iframe.src     = URL.createObjectURL(i_blob);
```

**So am looking for the best way to load the HTML code block into the iframe's src and hopefully without any error. I would appreciate any contribution.**

Comment: _“but it wont work because it would overide the iframe src”_ - and that would be a problem _why_ …?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-srcdoc would probably be the easiest way - if you can do without IE/Edge compatibility :-)

Comment: @04FS I need to place the HTML code inside the info.html, not override it. Also, the IE/Edge incompatibility would be an issue. Thanks

Comment: _“I need to place the HTML code inside the info.html, not override it.”_ - that’s not what your approach with document.write would have done to begin with - that _replaced_ the current document. Plus, it is not even clear what you actually mean by that, resp. why it would be important. Please explain.

Comment: @04FS Sorry it's not clear, I would explain. The src is *info.html*, and I initiate document.write to load the HTML code. I simply want to use an alternative to document.write to load the code. If I do `iframe.src  = URL.createObjectURL(i_blob);`, it simply override the info.html which I don't want.

Comment: _“it simply override the info.html which I don't want”_ - but _why_? What do you care, whether an _empty_ document gets “overwritten”? What part of _nothing_ is so important, that you want to keep it?